# print edited list without actually editing the list

Tags: python, list, printing

I want to print this list of lists with numbers before each individual list. Basically, I want to change each row so that row[0] has a number before it, and then run that row through .join(). How can I do this without actually editing the row in in my main list, board?

```
board = [["-"]*9 for i in range(9)]

def print_board(board):
    counter = 0
    for row in board:
        counter += 1
        row_for_printing = row
        row_for_printing [0] =  str(counter) + "   " + row[0]
        print "   ".join(row_for_printing)
        print " "
```

Comment: Just for clarification, can you show an example of the output format you're looking for?

Comment: if you are just printing you are actually not editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend the number, using string formatting, for example:

```
print '{}{}'.format(counter, "   ".join(row))
```

Use the `enumerate()` function to generate your counter:

```
def print_board(board):
    for counter, row in enumerate(board, 1):
        print '{}  {}'.format(counter, "   ".join(row))
```

Demo:

```
>>> print_board(board)
1  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
2  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
3  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
4  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
5  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
6  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
7  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
8  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
9  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

Comment: In case the guy is not on 2.7, positional arguments `{0}{1}` on `format()` is better.

Comment: That works. But suppose I wanted to print stuff in the middle of the list, how could I do that?

Comment: @Nathan: You can slice the list and format different portions differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about `enumerate()`, plus about printing two values in same line:

```py
board = [["-"]*9 for i in range(9)]

def print_board(board):
    for counter, row in enumerate(board, start=1):
        print counter, ''.join(row)
```

For more details on `enumerate()`, see [its documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

When it comes to `print` statement, if you will supply several variables separated with commas, they will be printed in same line, separated by single spaces:

```
print 'a', 'b', 'cc'  # this will print "a b cc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing will achieve the result you want - note that generating the output does not alter the data in each row (note that strings are immutable anyway..)

Here's a legible version of your code that does the printing you want in a function:

```
board = [["-"]*9 for i in range(9)]

def print_board(board):
    counter = 1
    for row in board:
        print "%d. %s" % (counter, row,)
        counter += 1
```

Or (note enumerate gives you a tuple containing the offset and value, offsets start at 0, so we add 1 to start counting from 1):

```
board = [["-"]*9 for i in range(9)]

def print_board(board):
    for pos, row in enumerate(board):
        print "%d. %s" % (pos+1, row,)
```